# Pyinstaller - libmagic not found after compiling app

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pyinstaller, libmagic

### Problem

I'm writing an application in Python. It works just fine in my python environment, but when I compile it with PyInstaller and try to run the resulting executable, I get the following error: `ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation`

I have a feeling that this has something to do with "python-magic-bin", an install containing the binaries that were required for a module named "magic", because if I uninstall "python-magic-bin" from my Python environment and try to run the app, I get the same exact error. I think that for some reason these binaries aren't being carried to the compiled exe.

If it makes a difference, I installed the "python-magic-bin" from a .whl file. This install added a folder called "libmagic" files libmagic.dll and magic.mgc to the directory that "magic" was installed to.

### Question

If I'm right about the problem, how do I get PyInstaller to carry over the binaries that "magic" needs?

### Recreate the Problem

The following can be done to recreate the problem:

1. Copy and paste this code into your editor. Save it as a file called
   "test.py"

   ```
   import magic

   m=magic.MAGIC_NONE
   print(m)
   ```
2. Download "python_magic_bin-0.4.14-py2.py3-none-win32.whl" from this link and use the following commands in the interpreter to install the required libraries to Python 3.6

   ```
   >>> pip install pyinstaller
   >>> pip install python-magic
   >>> pip install python_magic_bin-0.4.14-py2.py3-none-win32.whl
   >>> pip install libmagic
   ```
3. Open a command prompt in the same directory as that "test.py" file and use the following command to compile the program using pyinstaller:

   ```
   > pyinstaller test.py
   ```
4. After it's done, move to the newly created /dist/test directory (`cd ./dist/test`) and run the .exe using:

   ```
   > ./test.exe
   ```

After running it, you should see an error reading: `ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation` and `Failed to execute script test`

**Spec File**

This is the spec file I'm using to compile my project.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Home_Python\\pytags'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
```

### Versions

For this project, I'm using:

- Python            3.6.3
- PyInstaller       3.3.1
- Libmagic          1.0
- Python-Magic      0.4.15
- Python-Magic-Bin  0.4.14

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: I actually liked how the OP phrased the question - I'm struggling with the same thing.  I suspect that pyinstaller needs something in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks that it doesn't have.

Comment: Suzanne, I actually figured out the problem not too long ago. I can't post it right now, but I'll reply to this thread with the solution when I can.

Comment: I had a similat problem with a package that I installed in a virtual environment only but had pyinstaller pull from the root pythn installation on C:\python. Did not give an error during pyInstaller compile but at runtime. Installed the package with pip und it worked afterwards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured the problem out after a couple of days, so I'm going to document my solution here for anyone who may be having the same problem in the future.

The issue is the method that `libmagic` uses to find the .dll file it needs to work properly.

Head over to `Lib/site-packages/magic` under your Python installation and copy the file named `magic.py` and the folder named `libmagic` into the directory of your Python project. After doing that, open up `magic.py` in your preferred IDE. If you head over to line 156, you'll see this bit of code:

```
bin_dist_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libmagic')
```

This is the line that is causing our problem. It looks for a folder called libmagic in the same directory as the `magic.py` file. Specifically, the issue here is that the `__file__` variable does not work the same when the file is frozen into a .exe file so I replaced `__file__` with `sys.executable`. The resulting line looked like this:

```
bin_dist_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'libmagic')
```

Save the file, compile your program, and copy the `libmagic` folder into the same directory as the resulting .exe file.

If you run the .exe, everything should now work properly.

If there's anything I could clarify or you have questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I will note that I also copied libmagic.dll and magic.mgc in the binaries= section of my .spec file.

Comment: If you don't want to manually copy the libmagic folder you can add in the spec file:
extra_files += [('venv/Lib/site-packages/magic/libmagic','libmagic')] and use that for "datas".

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want to put this in another comment because it wouldn't be so visible...

This works for me. Just change the .spec file to include extra files:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

extra_files = [('venv/Lib/site-packages/magic','magic')]

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Home_Python\\pytags'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=extra_files,
             hiddenimports=[],

...
```